# Как подставить данные из массива в переменные в PHP-письме?

Tags: php, форма

Сорри за может быть глупые вопросы, только начинаю изучать PHP.

Есть форма, в ней пять чекбоксов вида:

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="form">
  <input class="main__input" type="checkbox" name="budget_01[]" value="Красный" id="red">
  <label for="red" class="main__label"><span>Красный</span></label>
  <input class="main__input" type="checkbox" name="budget_01[]" value="Зеленый" id="green">
  <label for="green" class="main__label"><span>Зеленый</span></label>
  <input class="main__input" type="checkbox" name="budget_01[]" value="Желтый" id="yellow">
  <label for="yellow" class="main__label"><span>Желтый</span></label>
  <input class="main__input" type="checkbox" name="budget_01[]" value="Фиолетовый" id="purpure">
  <label for="purpure" class="main__label"><span>Фиолетовый</span></label>
  <input class="main__input" type="checkbox" name="budget_01[]" value="Синий" id="blue">
  <label for="blue" class="main__label"><span>Синий</span></label>
  <button type="submit" class="button"
</form>
```

Кроме чекбоксов на сайте есть текстовые инпуты и их много, поэтому для отсылки данных пользуюсь FormData:

```
const dataForm = new FormData(form);
const user = {};

dataForm.forEach((val, key) => {
   user[key] = val;
});
```

Сформировал PHP-шаблон письма. С текстовыми инпутами все ОК, они нормально подставляются в переменные.

Для подстановки чекнутых чекбоксов создал для каждого свою переменную со значением "не определено". Хочу, чтоб если в массиве присутствует чекнутый чекбокс, его значение подставлялось заместо "не определено".

```
$budget01_01 = "не определено";
$budget01_02 = "не определено";
$budget01_03 = "не определено";
$budget01_04 = "не определено";
$budget01_05 = "не определено";
$budget_01_arr = $_POST['budget_01'];

if (!empty($_POST['budget_01'])) { 
  foreach($_POST['budget_01'] as $value) {
    $budget_01_arr .= $value;
  }
}

$body = "<h2>New contact</h2>
<tr style='background-color: #f8f8f8;'>
<td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>.$budget_01_arr.</b></td>
</tr>";
```

Два вопроса:

1. Почему в письме ничего не приходит, связанное с чекбоквами (инпуты подставляются, потому что на них заранее установлены переменные)?
2. Как вообще работать с ошибками в PHP, если сайт написан на HTML? Как-то вывести их в консоль нельзя? Как вообще с ними работают?
3. Ну и, если не сложно, подскажите, как все-таки подставить значения в переменных? Мне же не нужно искать, какие чекбоксы помечены, придут только помеченные чекбоксы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: на 1,2 пункты - ответ выше. на 3 - что придёт - будет в массиве `$_POST['budget_01']`. поэтому что-то подставлять куда-то совершенно не требуется

Comment: К сожалению, там нет ответа на мой вопрос. Ведь я написал выше, что сайт написан не на PHP, я работаю только с собирателем писем. И как вывести что-то на экран при помощи echo, если не предполагается работать с экраном? Все ответы, которые там есть, касаются либо локального сервера, либо если сайт написан на PHP. У меня ни того ни другого

Comment: То есть метка PHP в вопросе и код PHP в вопросе и  фраза "Сформировал PHP-шаблон письма" - это не PHP?

Comment: "У меня ни того ни другого" А что тогда у тебя есть?

Comment: Не понял вопрос

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я пользовался статьями, в которых описывается, как получить заполненные чекбоксы в собственный массив. Именно для этого нужно было ставить для чекбоксов одинаковое название атрибута "name" с квадратными скобками в конце. Но при создании json у меня уже в JS перебираются все активные инпуты (в т.ч. чекбоксы) и записываются в подмножество 'user', каждый объект со своими свойствами. Поэтому в этом подмножестве никакого массива 'budget_01' не было. Мне просто нужно было создать для каждого инпута свою переменную и перебрать все переменные циклом:

```
HTML
<input class="main__input" type="checkbox" name="budget_01_01" value="Красный" id="red">

PHP
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

if (!empty($obj['budget_01_01'])) {
  $budget_01_01 = $obj['budget_01_01'];
} else {
  $budget_01_01 = "не определено";
}
```